# $limit in mongodb aggregation as an optional parameter?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have an api with one optional parameter called limit, which takes an integer and limits the number of documents returned from the api in a get request.

Implementing this limit is fine in my PHP application when it is a required parameter, but when its not specified as part of my get request, what is the best way to handle it?

is there for example, a way to define $limit and set it to all documents? (in pseudo code, $limit = none)

```
$list = $collection->aggregate( array( array('$match' => array( ... )),
  '$project' => array ( ... )), '$limit' => intval($this->limit) ));

$this->limit //this is the optional input parameter
```

As you can see above, when the limit parameter is required it functions as required. Now when its ommitted, how can I keep the above code but specify no limit?

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: keep the same block in if else condition. Though it is not good solution where you fetch data from DB without limiting your result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually generate your where clause.

```
// Declare a where clause with your fixed conditions
$whereClause = array(array('$match' => array(...)), array('$project' => array(...)));

// Check if there's a limit
if($this->limit != 0)
    array_push($whereClause, array('$limit' => $this->limit));

// Finally, call with the where clause we've generated above
$list = $collection->aggregate($whereClause);
```

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, this is very clear and concise, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Comment: Just simply pass in the 0. "A limit() value of 0 (i.e. .limit(0)) is equivalent to setting no limit."

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No!

But, you can use an if/else condition like this:

```
<?php

if(intval($this->limit) != 0 ) {
    $list = $collection->aggregate( array( 
        array('$match' => array( ... )),
        array('$project' => array ( ... ))
        array('$limit' => intval($this->limit)) 
    );

    ));
} else {
    $list = $collection->aggregate( array( 
        array('$match' => array( ... )),
        array('$project' => array ( ... )), 
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but as you know I've omitted a lot of code and I thought there'd be a more efficient way of doing this? Seems like the developers of MongoDB could have added an 'exception' character for this purpose?